# ANDing Like wildcard search using multiple keywords contained via mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Trying to do a search using (LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND ) rather than (LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR ) using mysqli prepared statements
Not sure if i have to use 'call_user_func_array' instead but doing it this way although it works, it only returns records if either of the words in the broken up search string is contained in the title, i need it to return only titles where all the words are contained in the title .

```
<?php        
        $searchstr    = $_POST['inputsearch'];  //Input string from form
        $searchwords  = split(" ",$searchstr);  //Breaking the string to array of words
        $totalwords   = count($searchwords);    //Total words to search for
        $ind          = 1;
        while(list($key,$val)=each($searchwords))
            {
            if(trim($val) !="" && strlen($val) > 0){ // check good words
              $bindingstring[$ind] = $val;            // create new array of words
              $ind++;
              }
            }
        $callsqli = $conn->prepare("SELECT mytitle,myad_id FROM classifieds WHERE mytitle like CONCAT('%', ?, '%')"); //prepare with wildcards
        if(!$callsqli) {
                      echo 'Wrong SQL: Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR; // oops
                      return 0;
                    }
        for($i=1; $i<=$totalwords; $i++){
          $callsqli->bind_param('s',$bindingstring[$i]);            // bind each value
          $callsqli->execute();
                }
          $callsqli->store_result();
          $callsqli->bind_result($mytitle,$myadid);                 // get each title and advert id
                while($callsqli->fetch()){                                 // fetch each result and display
            echo "<a href='http://www.somesite.com/someview.php?&someitem=".$myadid."'>".$mytitle."</a><br />";
                }
                $callsqli->free_result();
                $callsqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: You need to generate the query string by iterating through the words: 
`if($i > 0)$query .="AND ";$query .= "mytitle LIKE concat('%',?,'%') ";` first then prepare and bind all of the words in then just run once the query

Answer (score 0):

I assume all your code works fine except for the sql part, so you need to generate sql string which includes the wildcard binds. You can do this by iterating through the words array and appending it to the query string. After the query is generated it is executed and results fetched:

```
    $searchstr    = $_POST['inputsearch'];  //Input string from form
    $searchwords = preg_split('/\s+/', $searchstr); //preg_split with whitespaces and tabs !!!
    $bindingstring = array();

    foreach($searchwords as $key => $val){
        $temp = strval(trim($val));
        if($temp != "" && strlen($temp) > 0){
            $bindingstring[] = $temp;
        }
    }

    $sql = "SELECT mytitle,myad_id FROM classifieds WHERE ";

    foreach($bindingstring as $key => $value){// generate the SQL
        if($key > 0){
            $sql .= "AND ";//dont include AND in the first iteration
        }
        $sql .= "mytitle LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') ";
    }
    echo $sql;
    $callsqli = $conn->prepare($sql); //prepare the query
    if(!$callsqli) {
        echo 'Wrong SQL: Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR; // oops
        return 0;
    }

    foreach($bindingstring as $key => $value){
      $callsqli->bind_param('s',$value);            // bind each value
    }

    $callsqli->execute();
    $callsqli->store_result();
    $callsqli->bind_result($mytitle,$myadid);                 // get each title and advert id

    while($callsqli->fetch()){// fetch each result and display
        echo "<a href='http://www.somesite.com/someview.php?&someitem=".$myadid."'>".$mytitle."</a><br />";
    }
    $callsqli->free_result();
    $callsqli->close();
```

EDIT: I edited the answer to use preg_split for separation of words by whitespace or tabs to get more consistent behaviour, also cleaned up the evaluation of the words and trimming to be more humanreadable

Comment: It fetches the titles fine, but only if any of the words that are in the submitted search sentence exist, but I need it only to return records if all the words in the sentence are found in the title.

Comment: This should do it then

Comment: I tried your code and if I only enter one word in the searchstring its fine, but if I enter two words its fails unless I manually enter the known amount of values ie. $callsqli->bind_param('ss',$value[0],$value[1]) but obviously I am not going to know how many words at design time.

Comment: Thanks for you help, managed to get it to work using str_repeat s's for the number of keywords ie 'sss' then adding the words into the array and calling  call_user_func_array.

Comment: Seems weird. What php version are you using?

Comment: Php version  5.6.32

Comment: Are you sure your word splitting was working before? That's where I think the problem was originally

Comment: Its possible than the list each function might have been incorrect but with the call_user_func_array its working sweet as a nut. although i am still using the "while(list($key,$val)=each($searchwords))"

Comment: I will redo as you showed again this evening and add some debugging to see where it is failing.